# I'm trying to parse a Json file from Airtable API, but it's not parsing empty fields or delimiters

Tags: python, json

I'm currently trying to parse some data from Airtable API, and to some extent, it has worked.

I did a lot of digging and found this pretty good resource: 
http://blog.appliedinformaticsinc.com/how-to-parse-and-convert-json-to-csv-using-python/

My problem is, when I try to put it into a Dataframe, the fields that are empty are not parsed, and cause the columns to get displaced, hence the dataframe is never properly built.

For example:

```
{'offset': --,
'records': [{'createdTime': time,
          'fields': {'A': '1',
                     'B': '2',
                     'C':  3,
                     'D': 'text',
                     'E':  object,
                     }]
```

Since I'm taking the first row of fields as dictionary keys, any time one of them is missing, for some reason it's not separated in the code and it would be like this:

```
 [{'createdTime': time,
      'fields': {'A': '1',
                 'B': '2',
                 'D': 'text',
                 'E':  object,
                 }]
```

And the script does not align it with its respective column. I need help because I've tried parsing the records in several ways and this is as close as I've gotten it to work. If anyone has experience with the Airtable API, it would be much appreciated. PowerBI queries can actually get the data properly so there must be a hidden separator somewhere in there.

I'm not super experienced in API requests, and I've mostly worked with non-complicated dataframes, so I humbly come to all of you for help.

Thanks in advance,
Matt

Comment: Can you add a more complete example of an api return value and the expected data frame you would like to build out of it?

Comment: Hello, the API returns an array of results (line = [time,fields,id]) formatted as objects in the json format quoted above.

I'm trying to parse and read every line out of the dictionary presented for the 'fields' column. So it would look like:
`*     [{'createdTime': time, 
*        'fields': {'A': '1',                    
*                   'B': '2',
*                   'D': 'text',
*                   'E':  object,
*                   }]`

Turning into:

`*index    A   B   C         D        E
*0            1   2   text   object
*1            1   2    3      text     object`

Comment: Hope that helps

Comment: This is no valid json (what is *time*, single instead of double quotes etc.). Please provide a valid input and the output in an unambigous tablular format. Please adjust in the question.

Comment: It's basically just a timestamp. I wrote it on a rush, but the dtype is datetime. It is unneeded for what I'm trying to build though. The information is private hence why I'm struggling to give you a better example.

Comment: Make a simplified valid example that has all the complexity you need and show the output you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the help, I already solved the main issue by applying pd.Series twice on the pagination.

```
import requests

headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer api_key','Content- 
type':'application/json'}
for offset in range(0, 1000,100):
    url = airtable_url + '&offset=' + str(offset)
    r = requests.get(airtable_url, headers=headers)
    x = pd.DataFrame(r.json())
    x = x['records'].apply(pd.Series)
    x = x['fields'].apply(pd.Series)
```

My main problem is I'm still getting only 100 records, but at least the dataframe is now proper.